# Displaying 2 Form Buttons next to each other in hidden div

Tags: html, css

I'm looking to have 2 buttons for forms that do 2 different actions when clicked shown next to each other

This is best explained on the following link:

http://jsfiddle.net/pfeHA/1/

The code involved is:

```
<div id="question" style="display:none; margin:0px;">
<form action="DoAction1" method="get">
<input type="submit"  value="Action1">
</form>
<form method="post" action="DoAction2">
<INPUT TYPE="submit" value="Action2">
</form>
</div>
```

This causes the buttons to display under each other, as shown by the link: http://jsfiddle.net/pfeHA/1/

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

add this in your CSS -

```
form{ display: inline-block; }
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pfeHA/3/)

Comment: If it's perfect then you should accept his answer. You may want to be a little more specific with that though, see my answer below. Setting the display to the form tag could cause issues with other forms later down the road.

Comment: What @RickCalder means is apply a class '.formWithButtons' to form element instead of writing CSS for the form element which can affect all forms in doc.

Comment: Just waiting for the accept cooldown and I will, i've just noticed it's effect on other forms, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
.formWithButtons{display: inline;}
```

To each of the forms holding the buttons http://jsfiddle.net/calder12/pfeHA/9/